# Making audio playlist by getting page's parent's ID

Tags: pages, shortcode, attachments, id, audio

So right now the site automatically creates pages when a post is updated. I want this page to include an audio playlist. So what I do, is simply add the shortcode: `[playlist]`.
Then, when the audio files are attached to the page, the playlist automatically generates.

I can confirm that this method works with specified IDs.

**The problem is**, that 3 different pages are made, and I need the audio to be attached to all three pages. So my solution is that I make a another page, set the audio files as children to that page, and make the original 3 pages children of the new page. Then I could use the `[playlist]` shortcode, but tell it to get the id from the parent page.

**Example:**

```
[playlist id="<?php get_parent_id ?>"]
```

or something like this.

The problem is that I cannot get the parent id. I've tried multiple different lines of code and nothing will work. The playlist just gets the default 0 ID, which it does when `id=""` is left blank.

This is all going into the `functions.php` file in my theme's directory.

--

Maybe there is a better way to do this, thusfar, this seems like the simplest solution, if only I can get the direct parent ID. It must exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution:**

Catalogue is a custom field in my post.

I make a 'dummy' page with just the catalogue number and attach the MP3s to this page.

```
$catalogue = get_field('catalogue');
$parent_id = get_page_by_title(strtolower($catalogue));  
$direct_id = $parent_id->ID;
$promo_page_content = [playlist id=" . $direct_id . '"]';
```

I realize this is most likely not the best way to write this. I am new to PHP. But for now, this will put it together. Hope this helps anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following function:

```
<?php get_post_ancestors( $post-ID ) ?>
```

The last post in the returned array should be the highest level ancestor.

This is from the Codex.

Comment: Thank you for replying! This actually returns a 1 when I print it, which I am still trying to understand.

Comment: It should return an array; using this in your page template, see if you can print_r the returned value and check out the array. The last item should be the highest level ancestor.

Comment: I solved it, I posted my solution. Thanks for your help, I used your advice to get the ID.